# Help creating textboxes via loop in aspx file

Tags: asp.net

I am having issues with giving id to a text box in the aspx for

heres my code

```
  <%for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)%>
    <%  {%>
          <div id="divPerson<%= i %>">

        <label for="txtFirstNameFriend<%= i %>">Friends First Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstNameFriend<%= i %>" MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <span id="ValFirstNameFriend<%= i %>" class="ValidationError" style="color:Red" visible="false" runat="server"><p>Please enter your First Name</p></span>
        <label for="txtLastNameFriend<%=i %>">Friends Last Name</label>
        <br />
        <label for="txtEmailAddressFriend<%= i %>">Friends Email Address</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddressFriend<%= i %>"  MaxLength="255" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <div style="display:none"><asp:TextBox ID="ValFriend<%=i %>" CssClass="ValFriend<%= i %>" MaxLength="255" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>

    <br />

          </div>

     <% } %>
```

Is there any way of adding in a dynamic id to a textbox created on the aspx file?

Comment: You can write php in any language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen the repeater control?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx